# How to get many times outputs interval time from geting one input in Python SimPy

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I using Python Simpy to simulation.

I want to generate products inventory(factory.stock) from a unit of raw materials(factory.materials).
After I got a unit of raw material,
I do not want to wait for a finished product inventory to be generated once at a time,
I want to generate multiple inventory at a certain interval of time each time,
For example I got a unit of raw material,get tree time products inventory,got 5products in each time,interval 6 unit time.

But my code delay() is used to delay time, but it does not work.
If I using yield to delay, it will got my raw material many times,and I only want to got a unit of raw material.

```
import simpy

class Factory():
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.materials = simpy.Container(env, capacity = 10000, init = 9000)
        self.stock = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity = 10000) 
        
def create_stock(env, factory):
    while True:
        print('time:{0} materials:{1} stock:{2}'.format(env.now,factory.materials.level,len(factory.stock.items)))
        yield factory.materials.get(1)
        
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(2):
                factory.stock.put({'order_id': 'order_id', 'id':j})
            delay(2)
        
        yield env.timeout(1)

        
def delay(how_long):
    yield env.timeout(how_long)   
    
env = simpy.Environment()

factory = Factory(env)
on_process = env.process(create_stock(env, factory))


print('start...')
env.run(until = 30)
print('end')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use yield from a generator,it works.When got one unit materials,every 3 unit time put out 2 stocks.

```
import simpy
class Factory():
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.materials = simpy.Container(env, capacity = 10000, init = 9000)
        self.stock = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity = 10000) 

def create_stock(env, factory):
    while True:
        #print('time:{0} materials:{1} stock:{2}'.format(env.now,factory.materials.level,len(factory.stock.items)))
        yield factory.materials.get(1)

        for i in range(5):
            yield from get_stock()

        

def get_stock():
    print('time:{0} materials:{1} stock:{2}'.format(env.now,factory.materials.level,len(factory.stock.items)))

    for i in range(2):
        factory.stock.put({'order_id': '', 'id':i})
    yield env.timeout(3)
    
    
env = simpy.Environment()

factory = Factory(env)
on_process = env.process(create_stock(env, factory))


print('start...')
env.run(until = 200)
print('end')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but `delay` doesn't work because the `yield` inside `delay` is not yielding to outside the function. It is different to have a function yield than to write `yield env.timeout(x)`.

Change the line `delay(2)` to `env.timeout(2)` would fix that problem

If you really want a function to do it, you can do

```
def delay(how_long):
    return env.timeout(how_long)

yield delay(2)
```

Comment: Think you for your answer.But Changing the delay(2) to env.timeout(2),it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I want to every 2 unit times to get some products inventory in 5 loops,and then exit process.
Changing the delay(2) to env.timeout(2),it does not work.

```
import simpy
class Factory():
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.materials = simpy.Container(env, capacity = 10000, init = 9000)
        self.stock = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity = 10000) 

def create_stock(env, factory):
    while True:
        print('time:{0} materials:{1} stock:{2}'.format(env.now,factory.materials.level,len(factory.stock.items)))
        yield factory.materials.get(1)

        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(2):
                factory.stock.put({'order_id': 'order_id', 'id':j})
            env.timeout(2)

        yield env.timeout(0)



env = simpy.Environment()

factory = Factory(env)
on_process = env.process(create_stock(env, factory))


print('start...')
env.run(until = 30)
print('end')
```

Answer (score 0):

you just needed to add a yield to your inner timeout
try this

```
import simpy
class Factory():
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.materials = simpy.Container(env, capacity = 10000, init = 9000)
        self.stock = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity = 10000) 

def create_stock(env, factory):
    while True:
        print('time:{0} materials:{1} stock:{2}'.format(env.now,factory.materials.level,len(factory.stock.items)))
        yield factory.materials.get(1)

        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(2):
                factory.stock.put({'order_id': 'order_id', 'id':j})
            #env.timeout(2)
            yield env.timeout(2)
            print('time:{0} materials:{1} stock:{2}'.format(env.now,factory.materials.level,len(factory.stock.items)))
            

env = simpy.Environment()

factory = Factory(env)
on_process = env.process(create_stock(env, factory))


print('start...')
env.run(until = 30)
print('end')
```